# How to deploy ruby on rails application with passenger and nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I am deploy a `ruby on rails` application with `passenger` and `nginx`, but it returns `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error`. `$WEB_APP/log/` doesn't have `production.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` doesn't exist.

here is my `nginx.cong`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        #root   /home/roger/tmp/html/;
        root    /home/roger/ruby_workspace/blog/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
}
```

Since I do not get any error log files, so I do not know what's wrong with my config?

Comment: One thing that stands out is you're missing a closing curly.  `sudo nginx -t` will test your conf files' syntax.  If you run `sudo service nginx restart` does it indicate 'fail' or 'OK'?  It prints on the far right of the terminal so it's easy to miss.

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` return `sudo：nginx: command not found`, `sudo service nginx restart` return `Restarting nginx: nginx.`.

Comment: `sudo：nginx` line has invalid char , so replace it to space

Comment: and please issue `find /var/log -name "*nginx*log"`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ what do you mean?`sudo nginx -t` is wrong?

Comment: @roger for you typing case yes, just use plain spaces

Comment: `find /var/log -name "*nginx*log"` return nothing. But I still don't understand, what's wrong with `sudo nginx -t`?